# Why android 12 have problems with bluetooth?

Tags: codenameone

I need help to solve the following problem.
When I deploy an apk to a device running Android 12, the app doesn't run and I see a pop up saying: Need android.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT. Any comment about it?
Thank you

added the permission in the codename_properties and I didn't succeed

Comment: Off-topic here.

Comment: This seems to be failing because [this code](https://github.com/codenameone/bluetoothle-codenameone/blob/master/CN1Bluetooth/native/android/com/codename1/bluetoothle/BluetoothLePlugin.java#L873C17-L873C34) seems to be out of date. I'm not sure if [this change](https://github.com/randdusing/cordova-plugin-bluetoothle/blob/master/src/android/BluetoothLePlugin.java#L919) is enough or not. Maybe [this too](https://github.com/randdusing/cordova-plugin-bluetoothle/commit/1c1d5ad799f8dfbe6f5babaa729e822575137f0b).

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question *Why android 12 have problems with bluetooth?* first, unfortunately, you forgot to read the [corresponding documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth/permissions).

With the update to Android 12 (API level 31), it is no longer sufficient to declare the permission required by the app, it is also necessary to obtain permission from the user of the mobile phone. The keyword is [Runtime permissions](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/permissions/overview#runtime)

Comment: This question is tagged codenameone so this answer is incorrect.

Comment: @ShaiAlmog I would like to contradict you. I do not see it as my job to do someone else's work. Rather, I want to give the OP the necessary tools to solve the problem independently and thus sustainably.
If he already has the skills to see the necessary permissions missing, he should know what functionality is missing or what to look for in case it is an obsolete software component.

Comment: Thanks Risto! But my problem is with CodenameOne, like Shai says previously.
Shai, exist option to runtime permissions with CN1 ??
Thanks a lot!!